# 2 way udp chat application

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to a UDP application in `C` where the application has to both send as well as received data simultaneously. Analogous to our chat applications. When 1 person is typing data, he should be able to receive it.

I am planning on how to implement this. Please help me if my thinking is correct.

1. The same program will act as client as well as server.
2. Both the servers will be listening on different ports
3. Create a thread for send and a thread for receive. ( pthreads )
4. I am facing a problem in this step. I want the recvfrom to be non-blocking. So i thought I can set E_WOULDBLOK and when errno is set to EAGAIN, i can yield the receive thread. But what happens when that socket is readable. How should i yield the send thread to make the the receive thread read the data. Also will it not affect the user if i yield the send thread when the user is typing just because my receive socket is readable?

Or else please suggest me methods to achieve this. Is pthread conditional variables apt for this scenario. Other ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach of using transmit and receive threads should work, but you later mention that you want to use non-blocking IO on the threads. This is fine, but I'm slightly puzzled why you want to use *both* non-blocking IO *and* threads at the same time.

If you're using threads, you don't need to mark the socket as non-blocking - just use standard blocking [`recvfrom()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html) and [`read()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) calls. When you get input on stdin from the `read()` in the sending thread then you send a message with [`sendto()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendto.2.html) and when you receive a message in the receiving thread you can display it to stdout as normal.

You shouldn't need a pthreads condition variable unless you're passing information between the threads - if you want more than a 2-way chat (i.e. multiple users) then you might need this.

If you're using non-blocking IO (which I think is the cleaner solution - threads are best avoided where possible), you shouldn't typically need to use threads - you can use functions such as [`select()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) and [`poll()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) to manage your file descriptors. I would recommend `poll()` as I think it has a more convenient interface, but either will work. There are also potentially more efficient equivalents such as [`epoll()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/epoll.7.html) on Linux, but generally you can ignore these unless your application will be handling large amounts of traffic.

You generally have a single thread with a loop. At the start of the loop you call `poll()` or `select()` and that will block until one of the file descriptors (which can be sockets) is read for reading or writing. You can listen on multiple file descriptors, but in your case it will work fine with a single one too.

Once the function returns, you can read information from the socket if it's indicated as "read-ready" by `poll()` or `select()`, and then send information as you like. If this was a connection-oriented socket you'd want to buffer output and monitor whether the socket was "write-ready" and flush your data from the output buffer as necessary. However, for UDP there isn't really a meaninful concept of "write-ready" so you can just send data whenever you have it available.

In fact, if you're using `poll()` or similar like this, you don't even need to mark the sockets as non-blocking. See my example code below, which implements a very simple UDP chat client. You have to specify the destination IP address and port manually on the command-line with this one and some of the error checking is very simple, because it's just example code, but it should give you enough to adapt to your own purposes.

You can test this on a Unix machine by compiling to a binary called "chat" and then opening two terminal windows and in one running:

```
chat 8888 127.0.0.1 9999
```

... and in the other one running:

```
chat 9999 127.0.0.1 8888
```

Note the first port is the listening port, and the remaining two arguments specify an IP address and port to connect to for the remote peer.

The code is here:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void start_chat(int sock_fd, struct sockaddr_in *peer)
{
  int ret;
  ssize_t bytes;
  char input_buffer[1024];
  char output_buffer[1024];
  struct pollfd fds[2];

  /* Descriptor zero is stdin */
  fds[0].fd = 0;
  fds[1].fd = sock_fd;
  fds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI;
  fds[1].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI;

  /* Normally we'd check an exit condition, but for this example
   * we loop endlessly.
   */
  while (1) {
    /* Call poll() */
    ret = poll(fds, 2, -1);

    if (ret < 0) {
      printf("Error - poll returned error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      break;
    }
    if (ret > 0) {

      /* Regardless of requested events, poll() can always return these */
      if (fds[0].revents & (POLLERR | POLLHUP | POLLNVAL)) {
        printf("Error - poll indicated stdin error\n");
        break;
      }
      if (fds[1].revents & (POLLERR | POLLHUP | POLLNVAL)) {
        printf("Error - poll indicated socket error\n");
        break;
      }

      /* Check if data to read from stdin */
      if (fds[0].revents & (POLLIN | POLLPRI)) {
        bytes = read(0, output_buffer, sizeof(output_buffer));
        if (bytes < 0) {
          printf("Error - stdin error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          break;
        }
        printf("Sending: %.*s\n", (int)bytes, output_buffer);
        bytes = sendto(sock_fd, output_buffer, bytes, 0,
                       (struct sockaddr *)peer, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        if (bytes < 0) {
          printf("Error - sendto error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          break;
        }
      }

      /* Check if data to read from socket */
      if (fds[1].revents & (POLLIN | POLLPRI)) {
        bytes = recvfrom(sock_fd, input_buffer, sizeof(input_buffer),
                         0, NULL, NULL);
        if (bytes < 0) {
          printf("Error - recvfrom error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          break;
        }
        if (bytes > 0) {
          printf("Received: %.*s\n", (int)bytes, input_buffer);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned long local_port;
  unsigned long remote_port;
  int sock_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;

  /* Parse command line arguments for port numbers */
  if (argc < 4) {
    printf("Usage: %s <local port> <remote host> <remote port>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  local_port = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
  if (local_port < 1 || local_port > 65535) {
    printf("Error - invalid local port '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }
  remote_port = strtoul(argv[3], NULL, 0);
  if (remote_port < 1 || remote_port > 65535) {
    printf("Error - invalid remote port '%s'\n", argv[3]);
    return 1;
  }

  /* Parse command line argument for remote host address */
  peer_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  peer_addr.sin_port = htons(remote_port);
  if (inet_aton(argv[2], &peer_addr.sin_addr) == 0) {
    printf("Error - invalid remote address '%s'\n", argv[2]);
    return 1;
  }

  /* Create UDP socket */
  sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sock_fd < 0) {
    printf("Error - failed to open socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  /* Bind socket */
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(local_port);
  if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)(&server_addr),
           sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
    printf("Error - failed to bind socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  /* Call chat handler to loop */
  start_chat(sock_fd, &peer_addr);

  close(sock_fd);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1.I spent the last 3 months building an epoll-server (and an http-server on top). It was non-trivial.

Comment: Things certainly are a little fiddlier with TCP. I think the main mistake a lot of people make is trying to cut corners (and this example is probably guilty of that, but it's just a sample). As long as you separate your poll layer into a separate module and have a clear API surrounding it, it's definitely tractable. There are a lot of fiddly issues to track down, however, like handling connection closures are odd times without going into tight `poll()` loops. Been there, done that, I feel your pain. If I have to do it again I'm tempted to just use [libev](http://libev.schmorp.de).

Comment: @Cartoo , thanks a lot for your suggestions. I dint see this further as no one replied for sometime. You took so much pains to explain. Thanks a ton